# Can Office Add in modify email message by adding digital signature from external source different than window keystore?

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I am currently working with outlook web add-in, I want to sign an email message without using window key-store.
How to get the content that use to sign?
And suppose I already have a pkcs7 signature,how to add it to email message?

Comment: Office.js add-ins do not activate on digitally signed or protected messages. Source ... [Mailbox items available to add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/#mailbox-items-available-to-add-ins). What's the reason to try to sign the message if you will not be ably to handle signed message with your add-in?

Comment: Thanks Slava Ivanov, I can't not give up just yet.  What about VSTO or COM, is it possible?

Comment: Absolutely possible, go wild with it. Just keep in mind by using this technology you will be limited to desktop Windows Outlook. Please refer to [How are Office Add-ins different from COM and VSTO add-ins?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins#how-are-office-add-ins-different-from-com-and-vsto-add-ins)